# syntax for selectbyexpression MTFCC in pyqgis

Tags: pyqgis

Does anyone know the correct syntax for the selectbyexpression processing algorithm for selecting MTFCC's? This is what I have right now, but it doesn't work so I'm guessing my problem lies in the syntax for the "expression" variable.

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
expression = '"MTFCC" = "H3010"'
processing.runalg("qgis:selectbyexpression", layer, expression, 0)
```

When I select by expression using the GUI, it shows something like "MTFCC" + "H3010" and gives me an output preview of 'S1400H3010' and I don't understand. Anything else I try just gives me an "expression invalid" error.

I am using pyQGIS v2.14.0

Comment: try `expression = QgsExpression(" \"MTFCC\" = \"H3010\" ")`

Comment: that gives me a "Problem executing algorithm: syntax error, unexpected LT" error in a small window

Answer (score 1):

Here it is. Changes to your code are provided below, followed by an explanation.

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
expression = "/"MTFCC/" = /"H3010 /" "  # note that I've modified this line
processing.runalg("qgis:selectbyexpression", layer, expression, 0)
```

Using `processing.alghelp("qgis:selectbyexpression")` I have seen that the function uses QString and not an Expression as a parameter. Thus there was no need to use `QgsExpression` as I've suggested before. Nevertheless, your syntax was wrong, since you misused `"`.

In general when you build a python string you will use `"..."` to define the places a string starts and ends. Similarly, you can involve both strings and variables to build a more complex expression, e.g. `"This string involves a" + variable + ", right?"`.

In your case you wanted an expression that calls a field, which in SQL looks like that: `"FieldName1" = "FieldName2"`. Python however reads two strings instead of one expression. The common slash (`/`) is used as an "exit" sign, and it indicates that the symbol that follows is a part of a string, and not a python function. Using `/ "` causes the interpreter to ignore any commands / activities related to this specific `"`. Finally it leads to this python expression: `" /"FieldName1/" = "/FieldName2/" "`.